# jQuery: Hyperlink in Dialog Closes Dialog Immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

We have a jQuery dialog box (an "Alert Box") which contains some text and a hyperlink. The hyperlink opens a new window. **We need to keep the dialog on the first page still open** when the link is clicked (and the second window is rendered). But the jQuery dialog closes automatically when the new window's URL finishes rendering.

Note that I am returning false; on the hyperlink, and it still closes the dialog on the 1st page. Any ideas?

Brief code snippets:

**alertBox.js**

```
ALERT_BOX = {
    open : function() {
        $('#alert_box').dialog("open").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
    },
    //...
```

**alertBox.jsp**

```
  ...
<span id="alert_msg" class="light-box-text"
     style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="window.open('validate.do','_blank'); return false;">
  Click here to view errors/warnings in a new window.
</a>
</span>
  ...
```

As far as I can tell, there are no other events forcing the dialog to close.

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle example of the issue?

Comment: have u tried to change `href="javascript:void(0)" ` to `href="#"`

Comment: @DanielSanchez - These are actually short snippets from a very complicated set of code, which does Ajax calls and returns this dialog after an Ajax call, so it's not feasible to use JSFiddle. However, do jQuery's Dialogs close automatically, or is there a way to debug what forces them to close?

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers - Yes, just tried it, still doesn't work, closes the dialog immediately when the link is rendered in the new window.

Comment: Have you tried the event.preventDefault() route? http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @DanielSanchez The preventDefault() almost worked, but still closed the dialog on the 1st page as soon as the 2nd page was done rendering. I verified that it was activated. If I just put in an alert('Test') in the script after preventDefault, it works, and keeps the dialog open. But there's something about rendering a page or submitting a request that closes it automatically.